# Add language change button for Azure AD b2c

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have Azure AD b2c authentication in my application,
how do I add Azure Ad b2c language change button in my login page, I need to add language change button in my login page if a user click on EN or FR buttons the login should display accordingly.

I went through Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/user-flow-customize-language but  I couldn't find anything talking about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll need to create a control in your custom HTML, eg a drop down to select language. Then, when the user select a new language, refresh the page with the respective `ui_locales` parameter in the URL.

Comment: Where do you add the script change event to perform this action ?

Comment: [custom html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow), [enable js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-user-flow)

Comment: Thanks it helped me to find a way to handle it

Answer (score 0):

It should be [default behaviour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#how-language-customization-works), either by specifying "ui_locales" as a query parameter or directly supported by your browser.

Comment: How to create buttons to handle change event for language changes on login page to use ui_locales

Comment: I don't want to use the default browser behavior, I want 2 buttons to click and set the language accordingly